# Jquery Debounce same scope for many events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Ben Alman's plugin to debounce some input events.
I want to specify different debounce time for different events, for example, a typing event can wait more than a change event.

Consider this code:

```
    $(function(){

        var changeInput=function(){
            console.log("change input call");
        };

        $("#test")
            .on("keyup",$.debounce(1000,changeInput))
            .on("blur",$.debounce(150,changeInput));

    })
```

This is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxmnc8b8/

With this code I would like to wait 1000ms in case of typing and only 150ms in case of blur (if user exit the input field I can accelerate the debounce call), **if you try to type something in the text field and quickly exit the input field you will get two calls of changeInput method** and not only one.

Is there a way to define a "scope" for debounce?

Answer (score 0):

You really not need any plugin, just use a timeout and e.g following logic (even i'd use onchange event instead of onblur, but...):

```
var i = 0; // just for DEMO purpose
$(function () {
    var changeInput = function (e) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("p").html(++i);
        }, e.type === "keyup" ? 1000 : 150);
    };

    $("#test").on("keyup blur", changeInput);
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: I know but I think a plugin is very useful to not copy-and-paste many blocks of code... I may need some other debouce in my application. If there is not any other way to do it, I will consider you solution. Thank you